# Proving that the atlas of an open submanifold is smooth

Tags: solution-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

$\def\AAA{\mathcal{A}}
\def\sbe{\subseteq}
\def\y{\psi}
\def\w{\omega}
\def\x{\chi}
$

In section $1.26$ of Lee's *Intro to Smooth Manifolds* the concept of an open submanifold is introduced, but it is not shown that the defined atlas is smooth: *"it is easy to verify that this is a smooth atlas for $U$"*:

[image]

---

**Is the following a proper proof for the smoothness of $\AAA_U$?**

*Proof:* The charts in $\AAA_U$ are smoothly compatible since $\AAA_U\sbe \AAA$, and it remains to be shown that $\AAA_U$ is maximal. If it wasn't there would be a chart $(V,\y)$ with $V\sbe U$ and smoothly compatible with every chart in $\AAA_U$, but not belonging to $\AAA_U$. We show $(V,\y)\in\AAA$, implying $\AAA$ is not maximal and causing a contradiction. Choose any chart $(W,\w)\in\AAA$. If $V\cap W = \emptyset$ we are done, otherwise we wish to show that $\w\circ\y^{-1}:\y(V\cap W)\to\w(V\cap W)$ is smooth. To do so choose $p\in V\cap W$ and a smooth chart $(X,\x)\in\AAA_U$ of $p$, so that
$$\w\circ\y^{-1}=\w\circ\x^{-1}\circ\x\circ\y^{-1}:\y(V\cap W\cap X)\to \w(V\cap W\cap X).$$
In particular, we have that $\w\circ\y^{-1}$ is smooth at $p$. Since $p$ is arbitrary, we get that $\w\circ\y^{-1}$ is smooth. Thus $(V,\y)$ is smoothly compatible with any smooth chart in $\AAA$, but does not belong to $\AAA$, contradicting $\AAA$'s maximality.